# Java: Math line design

Tags: java, math

Have anyone seen this mathematic line design before and perhaps have some pointers on how to generate it? Preferably using Java.

[image]

Comment: It looks very similar to a problem where 4 dogs, on vertexes of a square.. starts running towards each other at equal speed. Each line here is a tangent, denoting current direction of dog at time t.

Comment: @Nishant: It sure did, thanks! =)

Comment: See http://mathtourist.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/square-pursuit.html which also points to an algorithm for drawing the figure.

Comment: It's just scaled and rotated squares drawn upon one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with the outer square (rectangle, quad).

```
1) Draw it.
2) Move each vertex 10 percent of the way towards its neighbor.
3) repeat starting at #1.
```

The slightly tricky part is in step 2. If you move vertex 1 toward vertex 2, then 2 toward 3, 3 toward 4, the last thing is to move vertex 4 toward where vertex 1 WAS - not where you moved it to. The simplest way is to make a copy of vertex 1 first - call it vertex 5 - and move each vertex toward the next one in the list.

10 percent is an adjustable parameter.
Now, to move some percent of the way you can use a weighted average:

```
x1 = x1 + (x2-x1)*p
y1 = y1 + (y2-y1)*p
```

where p is 0.1 for 10 percent.

This ensures that the new vertex lies on the line drawn between the 2 old verticies in each case. It works with all quads, not just squares. This is also the beginning of understanding splines.